# Loading icon keeps loading when submit is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

We having a slight issues with our mobile forms

I have a mobile form that our users use to send us contact request. The problem we have is that when they press submit the loading icon keeps going even though the form has been submitted and the the data received. We still get the data but it does not look very professional as the user does not know if the form has gone and could resubmit the web form leading to double submissions

Thank you very much for your help in advance

```
  <!DOCTYPE html> 
  <html>
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc1/jquery.mobile-  1.0rc1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc1/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.js">               </script>
   </head> 


<body> 

  <div data-role="page">

<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Hire </h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">   
    <form action="thankyou2.php" method="POST">


        <!--    Wrap Inputs in fieldcontain which will sort out borders and padding, can    cause layout to break   -->
         <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="firstName"> Your Name: </label>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="" id="firstName" />      <!-- Use id and name values  -->
        </div>  

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="lastName"> Your Email: </label>
            <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="lastName" />     <!--  Use id and name values  -->
        </div>  
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="lastName"> Event Description </label>
        <textarea    rows=7 name=message></textarea> <!--   Use id and name values  -->
        </div>  



        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Request" data-theme="b" />
        </div>

    </form> 
</div>

<div data-role="footer">

</div><!-- /footer -->

  </div>
    <script>

   $('form').submit( function(e) {

    var vals = $(this).serialize();
    $.post( 'thankyou2.php', vals, function (data) {
     });

    e.preventDefault();
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You mean the loading icon of the browser or one that you implemented?

Comment: @Chris Campbell : can you please post a working demo.

Comment: Its the jquery spinner that keeps loading

Answer (score 0):

what you are doing is not specifing what to do on succes or error.

try the following

```
$("#btnId").click(function(e) {  
e.preventDefault();
   //show loading animation

   $.ajax({
   ...
   success:function(data){
      //remove loading animation
   },
   error:function(){//remove loading animation
   }
   });
});
```

I hope this helps.

Edit: I'm sorry i automaticly made it ajax.. for a non-ajax approach try the next:

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
$('#loading_image').show();
$.post('/somepage.htm', function() {
    $('#loading_image').hide();
});
```

});